# Position controller in Gazebo for Panda Arm

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make the panda arm work with the MoveIt [jog_arm](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/master/moveit_experimental/moveit_jog_arm) package in Gazebo. The original configuration for the Panda arm in the [panda_moveit_config](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config) package uses `effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController`. However, this is not supported by the `jog_arm` package which requires either `JointGroupVelocityController` or a `JointGroupPositionController`.

So I thought to edit the controller to use a supported controller: `position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController`. I made the following changes:

- Changed transmission hardware interface in the URDF from `hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface` to `hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface`
- Modified the `controller.yaml` file to start with `position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` instead of `effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` as well as loading the `position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController` required for the `jog_arm` package
- Modified the launch file to take into account the above change

When I run the launch file, the controller loads fine apart from warnings about missing PID gains but the robot is stuck in a collision state with itself.

- EDIT * I should add that when I try to plan in rviz to move the robot out of the collision state, I get the following error:

> Motion planning start tree could not
> be initialized!

So my questions are:

1. What is causing this self-collided state which doesn't occur when using the effort controller?
2. What actually determines the initial robot pose in the Gazebo simulation?
3. Is there another better approach to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345721/position-controller-in-gazebo-for-panda-arm/) by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2020-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So it seems like this problem was addressed [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/commit/2c118fc746f1ec5306369d48e572c7c6f32b5776) but doesn't seem to be working for me. As a workaround, I added initial joint positions in the launch file when spawning the robot in Gazebo:

```
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model panda -J panda_joint4 -1.571 -J panda_joint6 1.571 -J panda_joint7 0.785 -unpause"/>
```

Note, that Gazebo needs to be started paused for the initial joint positions to be set correctly as I believe this is a bug in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) with karma: 61 on 2020-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2